# How to share folders in Hyper-V with guest Ubuntu server & desktop 22.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, shared-folders

I have checked many guides that use `XRDP` to start a `remote desktop service` on Ubuntu desktop for getting the "`Enhanced Session`" to work.

https://4sysops.com/archives/activate-enhanced-session-mode-for-ubuntu-vms-in-hyper-v/

**But there is a problem for using this solution.**

The VM will be `open to the public` and anyone `in the same network` will be able to "remote desktop" into the Hyper-V VM.

This is not a **`SAFEY`** solution at all. It is a **`RISKY`** solution.

**VMWare workstation can share folder without any VNC and Remote Desktop.**

I want to make the "`Copy & Paste`" to work in Ubuntu 22.04 guest VM, and also want to `share folders` to the VM like `VMWare workstation` does.

Is there any `safe-enough solution (without opening network to the public)` for sharing folders between Hyper-V host and Ubuntu 22.04 guest VM?

Comment: If you just want to share folders, why use RDP?

Answer (score 2):

I know how to do it on a Windows Host

I know a way to share a folder in the host to an internal Ubuntu/RedHat folder, I know it works in these linux distros.

Create any folder on your computer:
then after creating the folder,
open Windows Powershell as administrator and type the following command:

```
New-SmbShare -Name smbsharename -Path folderpath
```

Then after that go get the IP address of your Wireless card

and log into your ubuntu 22.04 as root with the command : sudo su

and finally type the last command:

```
mount //yourip/smbsharename /folderinguestsystem -o
username=usernameofhost,password=passwordofhost
```

replace "yourip" with the IP address of your wireless card

replace "smbsharename" with the name of the smbshare you created earlier

replace "folderingguestsystem" with an existing folder in your Ubuntu system eg: "/home/user/downloads"

replace "usernameofhost" with your host's account username (not the guest system)

replace "passwordofhost" with the previously specified username account password of your Host system

and pressing enter if all goes well the folder will be mounted in the guest system and you can use it as if it were a shared folder.

I remind you that the folder you will need to use will be the one you specified after the SmbShare name

I hope everything is clear

**I update the answer:**

Ah I noticed a problem!
When I tried to create/copy/put a file inside the mounted folder it says "permission denied" to solve this problem just write this simple command on Windows Powershell as administrator:

```
Grant-SmbShareAccess -Name yoursmbsharename -AccountName "Everyone" -AccessRight Full -Force
```

And after that you will also be able to put the files in the mounted folder from the Ubuntu guest, sorry I just noticed that

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to safely share folders between host and guest, create in
the host a share on the folder that only you can access over the
network.

On Windows,
you may share a folder by right-click and selecting Properties.
In the Sharing tab, choose your share method and the accounts that
are allowed to access it.

In the VM, run Explorer (or its equivalent on Linux) and
find your host computer on the network, and access this share.
You will need to enter your account name and password.